# scikit learn: custom classifier compatible with GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have implemented my own classifier and now I want to run a grid search over it, but I'm getting the following error: `estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
TypeError: fit() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

I followed [this tutorial](http://danielhnyk.cz/creating-your-own-estimator-scikit-learn/) and used [this template](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/project-template/blob/master/skltemplate/template.py) provided by [scikit's official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html). My class is defined as follows:

```
class MyClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, lr=0.1):
        self.lr=lr

    def fit(self, X, y):
        # Some code
        return self
    def predict(self, X):
        # Some code
        return y_pred
    def get_params(self, deep=True)
        return {'lr'=self.lr}
    def set_params(self, **parameters):
        for parameter, value in parameters.items():
            setattr(self, parameter, value)
        return self
```

And I'm trying to grid search throw it as follows:

```
params = {
    'lr': [0.1, 0.5, 0.7]
}
gs = GridSearchCV(MyClassifier(), param_grid=params, cv=4)
```

**EDIT I**

This is how I'm calling it:
    gs.fit(['hello world', 'trying','hello world', 'trying', 'hello world', 'trying', 'hello world', 'trying'],
           ['I', 'Z', 'I', 'Z', 'I', 'Z', 'I', 'Z'])

**END EDIT I**

The error is produced by `_fit_and_score` method in file `python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py`

It is calling `estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)` with 3 arguments, but my estimator only have two, so the error makes sense for me, but I don't know how to solve it... I also tried adding some dummy arguments to `fit` method but it didn't work.

**EDIT II**

Complete error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rodrigo/no_version/text_classifier/MyClassifier.py", line 355, in <module>
    ['I', 'Z', 'I', 'Z', 'I', 'Z', 'I', 'Z'])
  File "/home/rodrigo/no_version/text_classifier/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 639, in fit
    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
  File "/home/rodrigo/no_version/text_classifier/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 779, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/home/rodrigo/no_version/text_classifier/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 625, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/home/rodrigo/no_version/text_classifier/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 588, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/home/rodrigo/no_version/text_classifier/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 111, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "/home/rodrigo/no_version/text_classifier/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 332, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/home/rodrigo/no_version/text_classifier/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/rodrigo/no_version/text_classifier/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/rodrigo/no_version/text_classifier/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 458, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
TypeError: fit() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

**END EDIT II**

**SOLVED**
Thanks you all, I had a stupid mistake: there was two different functions with same name (fit), (I implemented the other for custom purposes with different parameters, as soon as I renamed my 'custom fit', it worked correctly.)

Thank you and sorry

Comment: How are you calling the grid search fit method? Also make sure you are returning `self` from the fit method. Your example does not reproduce the error.

Comment: Yes, I'm returning self in fit method

Comment: What is your exact call to `gs.fit`?

Comment: Also can you include the exact error output

Comment: Here it goes:
Complet error output:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
class MyClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
     def __init__(self, lr=0.1):
         self.lr = lr
         # Some code
         pass
     def fit(self, X, y):
         # Some code
         pass
     def predict(self, X):
         # Some code
         return X % 3

params = {
    'lr': [0.1, 0.5, 0.7]
}
gs = GridSearchCV(MyClassifier(), param_grid=params, cv=4)

x = np.arange(30)
y = np.concatenate((np.zeros(10), np.ones(10), np.ones(10) * 2))
gs.fit(x, y)
```

The best I can figure is that you are passing something into the `gs.fit` method beyond `x` and `y` or your `MyClassifier.fit` method is missing the self argument.

The `fit_params` kwargs should only be populated if you pass a kwarg to the `gs.fit` method otherwise it is an empty dictionary (`{}`) and `**fit_params` won't throw an argument error.  To test this create an instance of your classifier and pass `**{}`. For example:

```
clf = MyClassifier()
clf.fit(x, y, **{})
```

This does not throw the positional arguments error.

Therefore, again unless something is passed to `gs.fit` e.g. `gs.fit(x, y, some_arg=123)` it would seem to me that you are missing one of the positional arguments in the definition of `MyClassifier.fit`. The error message you included seems to support this hypothesis as it states `fit() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. If you had defined fit as follows it would take 3 positional arguments:

```
def fit(self, X, y): ...
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation on fit_params! I already solved my problem, it was an stupid error, sorry (I edited my original post also)

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a through-passing of some custom parameters. Just add a catch-all keywords argument to you fit-Method:

```
def fit(self, X, y, **_k):
    ...
```