# Parameters are not going to custom estimator in scikit-learn GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parameter-passing, gridsearchcv

I'm trying and failing to pass parameters to a custom estimator in scikit learn. I'd like the parameter `lr` to change during the gridsearch.
Problem is that the `lr` parameter is not changing...

The code sample is copied and updated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211590/scikit-learn-custom-classifier-compatible-with-gridsearchcv)

(the original code did neither work for me)

Any full working example of `GridSearchCV` with custom estimator, with changing parameters would be appreciated.

I'm in `ubuntu` 18.10 using `scikit-learn` 0.20.2

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
import numpy as np

class MyClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):

     def __init__(self, lr=0.1):
         # Some code
         print('lr:', lr)
         return self

     def fit(self, X, y):
         # Some code
         return self

     def predict(self, X):
         # Some code
         return X % 3

params = {
    'lr': [0.1, 0.5, 0.7]
}
gs = GridSearchCV(MyClassifier(), param_grid=params, cv=4)

x = np.arange(30)
y = np.concatenate((np.zeros(10), np.ones(10), np.ones(10) * 2))
gs.fit(x, y)
```

Terveisin, Markus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were not able to see the change in `lr` value since you are printing inside constructor function.

If we print inside `.fit()` function, we can see the change of `lr` values. 
It happens because of the [way](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L677) the different copies of estimators are created. See [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e92acf49d46251479b75c88cba632de1937/sklearn/base.py#L32) to understand the process for creating multiple copies.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
import numpy as np

class MyClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):

    def __init__(self, lr=0):
         # Some code
        print('lr:', lr)
        self.lr = lr

    def fit(self, X, y):
         # Some code
        print('lr:', self.lr)
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
         # Some code
         return X % 3

params = {
    'lr': [0.1, 0.5, 0.7]
}
gs = GridSearchCV(MyClassifier(), param_grid=params, cv=4)

x = np.arange(30)
y = np.concatenate((np.zeros(10), np.ones(10), np.ones(10) * 2))
gs.fit(x, y)
gs.predict(x)
```

Output:

```
lr: 0
lr: 0
lr: 0
lr: 0.1
lr: 0
lr: 0.1
lr: 0
lr: 0.1
lr: 0
lr: 0.1
lr: 0
lr: 0.5
lr: 0
lr: 0.5
lr: 0
lr: 0.5
lr: 0
lr: 0.5
lr: 0
lr: 0.7
lr: 0
lr: 0.7
lr: 0
lr: 0.7
lr: 0
lr: 0.7
lr: 0
lr: 0.1
```

Comment: So if I want to create an attribute of `MyClassifier` based on some argument value in the constructor, does this mean I can't have this code inside the `__init__()` of `MyClassifier`? For example `if lr != 0: self.nonzero = True else: self.nonzero = False`

Comment: yes, you cann't have additional parameters defined inside `__init__()`. Btw, you can create these attributes outside constructor. like the `feature_importance_`  attribute of decision tree

Comment: I see. So I would simply need to call a different method to do run the additional code before returning the value of my new attribute? For example `self.nonzero = check_non_zero_lr()` And `def check_non_zero_lr(): if self.lr != 0: return True else: return False`

Comment: You can use it as property and not store that into a variable. example [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f1111be2fa9899a610843c36d203b0fab02f16c3/sklearn/ensemble/_voting.py#L51).

Comment: If you stil need clarification please ask a fresh question with more details. People would be happy to help you.

Comment: Done. Posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64532894/11542679)

Comment: Good. You hav got a great answer.

Comment: Yes, I sorted it out.